# On Virial theorem and its Quantum mechanical analog

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics, hydrogen, virial-theorem

The relation established by the [virial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) is well pronounced in the case of potential energies that are power law functions of distance. In quantum mechanics, a similar analog is present, although it's not for the time average but rather is for the expectation value. Like for a hydrogen like atom (reference:  [Quantum Mechanical Problems,Constantinescu and Magyari](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MvxFBQAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&lpg=PP1&dq=Constantinescu+and+Magyari&source=bl&ots=jHuUJzBWnu&sig=G84DgAe4BWHORWt2QODWl8ZXARg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLuPff6ZbQAhVKRI8KHSxRAEwQ6AEIVTAR#v=onepage&q=Constantinescu%20and%20Magyari&f=false) problem 3/8).

My question is how do we examine the case of a dielectronic helium atom, where electric interactions are mediated by $n = −1$ [powerlaw functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) between each pair of particles. Would the virial theorem hold? What would be the effects of the [interchange interaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction) of quantum mechanics?

**Note**: Power law functions as mentioned in Landau and Lifshitz Vol.I

Comment: Hi, do you  mean hydrogen (in your tag) or helium (in your post). Also, what is an interchange interaction, an exchange of particles I guess. Thanks

Comment: @CountTo10 I have added hydrogen tag because I have initially mentioned about the QM of hydrogen like atoms, can understand the confusion, will edit the question. Thanks. For the latter question you have asked please see this- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction , I'll add this edit too